# icp segmentation fault PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

i'm trying to use the icp algorithm to align 2 RGBD cloud, but the function align results in segmentation fault and i don't know why and how to fix this, if anyone can help-me i will be grateful

this is a example of what i'm trying to do.

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
vector<int>index;
pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_in,*cloud_in,index);    
pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_out,*cloud_out,index);  
 icp.setInputCloud(cloud_in);
 icp.setInputTarget(cloud_out);
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
 icp.align(Final);
```

Comment: Can you show both the CMake file and full source file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the input point cloud was an ordered point cloud (with resolution 48x64) and containing NaNs. Even though I applied pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud, nan values were still there. I solved the problem by converting my ordered input point cloud to an unordered point cloud (Nx3) before processing.

If your cloud_in is an ordered point cloud too, try converting it to unordered first as following:

```
cloud_in->width    = cloud_in->width * cloud_in->height;
cloud_in->height   = 1;
cloud_in->is_dense = false;
cloud_in->points.resize (cloud_in->width * cloud_in->height);

// Then remove NaNs and apply ICP
```